# Kendo dropdown giving [Object Object] when binding values dynamically from array

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

This is my code:

```
var arr = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < GanttData.length; i++) 
     {  arr.push({"text":GanttData[i].Projectname,"value":GanttData[i].Projectuid});}   

var dropdownlistF = $("#drp_resources").data("kendoMultiSelect");
dropdownlistF.setDataSource(arr);
```

But it's not working. Any help will be blessing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you defined the widget parameters. According to MultiSelect docs the default text field name it will look for in  the data is `''`([`dataTextField`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/configuration/datatextfield)), so you need to set it:

```
$("#drp_resources").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataTextField: 'text'
});
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <select id="drp_resources"></select>
  <script>
  var arr = [],
      GanttData = [{
        Projectname: 'test', 
        Projectuid: 123
      }];
    
    $("#drp_resources").kendoMultiSelect({
      dataTextField: 'text'
    });

   for (var i = 0; i < GanttData.length; i++) 
       {  arr.push({"text":GanttData[i].Projectname,"value":GanttData[i].Projectuid});}   

  var dropdownlistF = $("#drp_resources").data("kendoMultiSelect");
  dropdownlistF.setDataSource(arr);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EgUYesET)